# Looking to create and add sample data into a sorted set using CompareTo

Tags: java, set, compareto, sorting, sortedset

I would like to create a sorted set with some sample data using CompareTo.

Can you provide some sample coding on how to do this?

Comment: This is a simple google search. Please use google before posting here on stuff like this. see here [Implementing compareTo](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a compareTo method in your class that you want to compare with others, and have the class implement comparable:

```
public class TestObject implements Comparable{
    private int a_number;

public int getNumber() {
   return a_number;
   }

public int compareTo(TestObject other) {
   return getNumber() - other.getNumber();
   }
}
```

You can now compare objects of this class with objects of the same class

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick responses and help.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>()
......
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyObject>(){
            public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
                return o1.myValue.compareTo(o2.myValue);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful code sample. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reading

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

and then reading how to use it in TreeSet

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html